# Extension Methods in C# - Is this correct?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have been delving into C# recently, and I wonder if anyone would mind just checking my write up on it, to make sure it is accurate?

Example: Calculating factorials with the use of an Extension method.

For example if you wanted to extend the int type you could create a class e.g.
`NumberFactorial` and create a method e.g. Static Void Main, that calls e.g. `int x = 3`
Then prints out the line (once its returned from the extension method)

Create a public static method that contains the keyword "this" e.g. this `int x`
perform the logic and the parameter is then fed back to the inital method for output.

The code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 3;
            Console.WriteLine(x.factorial());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public static class MyMathExtension
    {
        public static int factorial(this int x)
        {
            if (x <= 1) return 1;
            if (x == 2) return 2;
            else
                return x * factorial(x - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would just be careful with your verbage.  `wanted to extend the int type`, you are adding an additional method for use within the int class.  Extend implies inheritence...

Comment: "Is this correct?" Well, I don't know. Does it produce the result YOU are looking for?

Comment: Everyone, calm down with the "not a real question" button. Relax. It's all good.

Comment: One quibble: You don't need the `if (x == 2) return 2;` or the `else`, but they won't harm your results.

Comment: Another quibble: method names in C# are generally written as PascalCase, not lowerCamelCase as they are written in, say, Java.

Comment: I wonder what's not real about this question... If closed, then at least migrate it to codereview in stead of as NARQ. Voted to re-open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

> Extension methods are defined as static methods but are called by using instance method syntax. Their first parameter specifies which type the method operates on, and the parameter is preceded by the this modifier. Extension methods are only in scope when you explicitly import the namespace into your source code with a using directive.

You can find out more about extension methods [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) and [here](http://creatingcode.com/2010/09/using-extension-methods-in-net/)

Answer (score 2):

It certainly looks accurate. However, I'm wondering why you would care to have two exit conditions when only one is really needed. Also, if you made the code, you should easily be able to unit test it to make sure it's accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me. By the way, you could also have done

```
public static class MyMathExtension
{
    public static int factorial(this int x)
    {
        if (x <= 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return x * (x - 1).factorial();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I view extension methods is in terms of discoverability and universal-ness.

For targeting a .NET built-in type I make serious considerations on the application intent. Using your example of factorial I would ask myself

> How often do I need myint.Factorial()?

The answer to this question for most domains would be, not many. With that in mind if I really needed to implement myint.Factorial() at this point I would take the class you have `MyMathExtension` and make that a private class inside of the class that will actually use the `Factorial` method. At this point it becomes just another internal, private helper method (I wish .NET allowed us to declare this inline with the class instead of being forced to create a shell class for no reason)

Now if your domain was a math application that for whatever reason uses the calculation of factorials extensively, *so much* so that you *wish* the int type itself implemented factorial.

At this point I would create the method in

```
namespace System {
    public class IntExtension {
        public int Factorial(this int....) 
    }
}
```

This specifically violates the Microsoft guidelines for extension method usage. Microsoft recommends that you do not use the namespace of the `this Owner obj` due to that namespace being outside of your domain. If I recall correctly, their primary justification of this reason is since that namespace is outside of your domain it's subject to mutation. I **substantially disagree** with the consclusion of Microsoft that the solution to this is to avoid it. My conclusion is should an assembly have breaking changes to be impacted by the namespace usage you would have related breaking changes and be required to forward migrate regardless and that now is the appropriate time to fix your consumption of their namespace internally also.

I feel it is best practice to scope your public extension methods to the namespace of the owned type. This for all intensive purposes makes your extension method class behave more in lines to a partial class of the same type. This goes back my original statement of viewing extension methods in regards to discoverabilty. Using the same namespace makes your extension fair more discoverable **especially** if you don't program with tools like Resharper.

Answer (score 1):

If it works, then I'd say it's correct.  The code you provide looks clean and right to me, but you should probably add some error guarding against negative numbers.

Comment: He does. If x is 0 or negative, it returns 1.

Comment: A factorial computation isn't even really valid for a negative number. The factorial is defined as the product of all positive integers less than or equal to it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial

Comment: I read somewhere that the result is undefined for negative numbers.

Comment: @Tejs: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-3%29%21  If it's not a valid input to our method, I'd throw an exception. If we want to change the method signature to somehow support a return value of Complex Infinity, then that's another option.

Comment: That's a reasonable explanation then. I'd throw an exception as well.